# Bridging two networks

Tags: router, switching, bridging

Good days everyday. I am a newbie networking. I just have a question.

[image]

The diagram above simplify my network setting. They are all in same location. Is there a way to connect from 192.168.0.XXX to 192.168.1.XXX network?

Second question, let say there is a incoming connection from 192.168.1.XXX, how can I route to 192.168.0.XXX network? Thank you all, much appericate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bridge - with a bridge, both networks become one, the DHCP servers will interfere, there's no security etc. *Routers* route between networks.

If you can throw a cable the simplest approach is to connect the two routers (using a dedicated subnet, preferably /31) and set up either static routes or a routing protocol like OSPF.

If you need to connect them across the Internet you'll need a site-to-site VPN link/tunnel - see Ron's answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a VPN to connect your two routers over the Internet.  In this way, one side can route traffic to the other.

You can [see an example here](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011377588-EdgeRouter-Route-Based-Site-to-Site-IPsec-VPN).